# If $n>1$ has $r$ different prime factors, then the totient is bounded by $\varphi(n) \geqslant n/2^r$?

Tags: prime-numbers

I want to prove that if $n>1$ has $r$ different prime factors, then

$$\varphi(n) \geqslant \frac{n}{2^r}.$$

Comment: By "fi", you mean Euler's totient function $\varphi$?

Comment: Yes. That's correct.

Comment: Do you know how one gets the totient from the prime factorisation?

Answer (score 1):

We have $\phi(n)=n\cdot\prod_{p\mid n}\left(1-\frac1p\right)$ and $1-\frac1p\ge \frac12$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following: if the prime decomposition of $\;n\in\Bbb N\;$ is

$$n=\prod_{k=1}^m p_k^{a_k}\;,\;\;a_k\in\Bbb N\implies\varphi(n)=n\prod_{k=1}^m\left(1-\frac1{p_k}\right)$$

and thus:

$$m=r\implies \varphi(n)=n\prod_{k=1}^{m=r}\left(1-\frac1{p_k}\right)\ge n\prod_{k=1}^{m=r}\left(1-\frac1{2}\right)=\frac n{2^r}$$